# Getting unintialized local variable used even though it was initialized it in the beginning

Tags: c++, loops

I have been trying to write a program that keeps looping unless a secret number is inputted, but whenever i input  the secret number . It gives me an error.

```
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int secretNum = 8;
    int guess= 0;

    while (secretNum != guess) {
        cout << "enter guess";
        cin >> guess;
    }
    cout << "you win";



}
```

Comment: The code you show [compiles with no warnings or errors](https://rextester.com/DAL13268) and runs successfully, once I add `#include <iostream>` at the top. To the extent there is a problem, it must needs lie in the code not shown.

Answer (score -1):

For testing purposes I was inputting random characters to see if the program keeps looping since its suppose to loop unless the secret number is given, and it was giving me an error because I was suppose to input numbers instead of characters.

Once I inputted integers , the program kept looping until I gave it the secret number.